# Best practice for mobile app service domain

Tags: dns, subdomain

We're developing a client-server game that communicates with our server in real time. During development we directed the client to the server's IP address directly.

Moving forward to release, we'd like to switch the target server IP to a domain name.

I'm looking for feedback whether we should use a sub-domain within our web-site main domain (say: server.mygame.com), or, setup a different domain for the game server (mygame-server.com).

If there is no difference either way I'd love to get feedback on that as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question might be better asked at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) because it is not strictly related to programming...

Anyway, providing my opinion on your quesion: I'd go for a *subdomain of a new game-related main domain*.

Here's why: this should give you the most flexability for future changes, assuming the following thoughts:

- A new domain especially for that game allows you to promote game information on the `www.` subdomain.
- The game endpoint sits (for example) at `api.` which points to a different server than any of the websites (improves stability, allows different software for same ports, e.g. web servers).
- You can add round-robin DNS load balancing (or any other load-balancing) later. This might be easier if this can be done on a spearate main domain.
- You don't have to mess with the main company DNS entries for any game-related settings, improving the stability of both services (as they are separated).
- If you might sell the game one day, and a different domain makes it easier to transfer all services and data.
- Using a subdomain makes it easier in general because normally the second-level domains (like the `A` record for `example.com`) is handled by the DNS servers at a "lower" level in "DNS authority tree" (e.g. at you DNS provider), so it might be more difficult to add special features like load-balancing there.

So these are only some thoughts. Basically it should not matter which way you set up the DNS entries, but if one of the topics above applies (or otherwise sounds reasonable) then you might choose a subdomain on a new domain ;)